# TokenKey from Stripe is not being send after submit

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe as payment method and I can't get the value of the stripeToken after submiting the paymente form. I been trying for hours figuring it out, with no success. I don't understand much of JS so I don't know if the problem is there. But it shouldn't be, since I saw the code elsewhere.

**Note**:

- @section('extra_head') is in the end of . @section('extra_js') is before the  . And  I created a Stripe account and the values of the keys in .env are mine.
- I don't know if this is a weird behaviour but I tried a few Exceptions (https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#exceptions)  and the only Exception shown was a common one from Laravel "UnexpectedValueException". Could it be that the package was not well installed? My auto-discovery is not working and I have laravel 8 (yeah, I know it's weird but it's true). Could it be that causing some bad installation?

If someone needs any more information, please let me know.

I'm using `cartalyst/stripe-laravel`, I installed as follow:

In `composer.json` I placed this -> `"cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "^13.0"` and then did `php composer update`.

**config/app.php:**

```php
// in providers array 

        Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\StripeServiceProvider::class,
...

// in aliases array

        'Stripe' => Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\Facades\Stripe::class,
```

**config/services.php:**

```
    'stripe' => [
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
    ],
```

**.env:**

```
STRIPE_KEY=<public_key>
STRIPE_SECRET=<secret_key>
```

Controller:

```php
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;
use Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\Facades\Stripe;
use Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\CardErrorException;
use App\Models\Product;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('checkout.list');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());

        try {
            $charge = Stripe::charges()->create(
                [
                    'amount' => Cart::total(), // amount in cents
                    'currency' => 'EUR',
                    'source' => $request->stripeToken,
                    'description' => 'Order',
                    'metadata' => [

                    ],
                ]);

            return back()->with('sucess', 'Testing');

        } catch(Cartalyst\Stripe\Exception\ServerErrorException $e) {

            $message = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

This is the checkout view, where the form is:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('extra_head')
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')

         <h1 class="checkout-heading stylish-heading">Checkout</h1>
        <div class="checkout-section">
            <div>
                <form action="{{ route('checkout.store') }}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <h2>Billing Details</h2>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        @if (auth()->user())
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ auth()->user()->email }}" readonly>
                        @else
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="half-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="city">City</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="province">Province</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="province" name="province" value="{{ old('province') }}" required>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end half-form -->

                    <div class="half-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="postalcode">Postal Code</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postalcode" name="postalcode" value="{{ old('postalcode') }}" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end half-form -->

                    <div class="spacer"></div>

                    <h2>Payment Details</h2>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name_on_card">Name on Card</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_on_card" name="name_on_card" value="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="card-element">
                          Credit or debit card
                        </label>
                        <div id="card-element">
                          <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer"></div>

                    <button type="submit" id="complete-order" class="button-primary full-width">Complete Order</button>



                </form>

            </div>



            <div class="checkout-table-container">
                <h2>Your Order</h2>

                <div class="checkout-table">
                    @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
                    <div class="checkout-table-row">
                        <div class="checkout-table-row-left">
                            <div class="checkout-item-details">
                                <div class="checkout-table-item">{{ $item->model->title }}</div>
                                <div class="checkout-table-price">{{ $item->model->price }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end checkout-table -->

                        <div class="checkout-table-row-right">
                            <div class="checkout-table-quantity">{{ $item->qty }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- end checkout-table-row -->
                    @endforeach

                </div> <!-- end checkout-table -->

            </div>

        </div> <!-- end checkout-section -->
    </div>

@endsection

@section('extra_js')

    <script>
        (function(){
                    // Create a Stripe client
                    var stripe = Stripe('{{ config('services.stripe.key') }}');
                    // Create an instance of Elements
                    var elements = stripe.elements();
                    // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
                    // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
                    var style = {
                                base: {
                                            color: '#32325d',
                                            lineHeight: '18px',
                                            fontFamily: '"Roboto", Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                                            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
                                            fontSize: '16px',
                                            '::placeholder': {
                                                        color: '#aab7c4'
                                                    }
                                        },
                                invalid: {
                                            color: '#fa755a',
                                            iconColor: '#fa755a'
                                        }
                            };
                    // Create an instance of the card Element
                    var card = elements.create('card', {
                                style: style,
                                hidePostalCode: true
                            });

                    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>
                    card.mount('#card-element');
                    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
                    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                                var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                                if (event.error) {
                                            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
                                        } else {
                                                    displayError.textContent = '';
                                                }
                            });
                    // Handle form submission
                    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
                                document.getElementById('complete-order').disabled = true;
                                var options = {
                                            name: document.getElementById('name_on_card').value,
                                            address_line1: document.getElementById('address').value,
                                            address_city: document.getElementById('city').value,
                                            address_state: document.getElementById('province').value,
                                            address_zip: document.getElementById('postalcode').value
                                        }
                                stripe.createToken(card, options).then(function(result) {
                                            if (result.error) {
                                                        // Inform the user if there was an error
                                                        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                                                        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                                                        // Enable the submit button
                                                        document.getElementById('complete-order').disabled = false;
                                                    } else {
                                                                // Send the token to your server
                                                                stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                                                            }
                                        });
                            });
                    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
                                // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                                var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                                var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
                                hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                                hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
                                hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);

                                form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
                                // Submit the form
                                form.submit();
                            }
                })();
    </script>

@endsection
```

**Debugging**

After dd($request->all() ) in store method the striveToken is missing:

```
array:9 [▼
  "_token" => "IWUpmaswjyWfMRGk8UWbc7kMzdJfUXhrlbU79Kht"
  "email" => "teste@gmail.com"
  "name" => "asdasda"
  "address" => "sdasd"
  "city" => "asdasd"
  "province" => "adsasd"
  "postalcode" => "asd"
  "phone" => "asd"
  "name_on_card" => "asdasd"
]
```

Comment: try to log `token` into `function stripeTokenHandler(token)`

Comment: check if stripe.createToken returns an error or you get the token. If you get the token check if stripeTokenHandler is being run and if it appends the hidden input to your form. My guess is it doesn't.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia  and Kopz Sorry for my ignorance, like I said I don't understand much of JavaScript... How could I do that?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Are you saying, inside the function do this "console.log('token')" ?

Comment: i mean `console.log(token)`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Weird, nothing showed up in the console. But the token for sure goes into the "var stripe"

Comment: @kopz I tried to do console.log('test') in stripe.createToken and in stripeTokenHandler. The message didn't show up, so that means those function are not being run. What could be the issue?

Comment: try `console.log("test")` at the beginning of `form.addEventListener`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thanks for the patience. Forgot to say, also tried that and it does not show (after submit also). Could it be bad installation? My auto-discovery is not working well. Btw, I did "composer show | grep stripe" and it shows "cartalyst/stripe                   v2.4.5  A comprehensive Stripe API package." and "cartalyst/stripe-laravel           v13.1.0 Laravel 8 integration for the Cartalyst Stripe package.". Even tho I only place "cartalyst/stripe-laravel": "^13.0" at the composer.json. Also, I checked the logs in Stripe and it receives request from API version "2017-06-05" ....

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia .... so I now added  " 'version' => '2017-06-05', " but not working still.